# zookeeper storm integration throws KeeperException$ConnectionLossException

Tags: apache-storm, apache-zookeeper

I am using `zookeeper` and `storm` integration.storm application is running properly for some time then giving `error`:

> org.apache.storm.shade.org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException$ConnectionLossException: KeeperErrorCode = ConnectionLoss

Comment: And what's the question???